# Spark Executors getting Terminated

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Experts, I am using Spark 1.6.0 with Python(2.7) and facing an issue where my job is getting terminated with below error message-

```
ERROR executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend: Driver 10.436.126.242:12345 disassociated! Shutting down.
```

What does this error message even mean? I tried to look for some help online but couldn't find much. Have any of you ever faced this error before?

My application is dealing with minimal amount of data and there aren't any resource intensive operation in the code. I have spent almost a day trying to resolve this issue. Any help is really appreciated.

Thanks!!

Comment: Please paste your spark-submit command, You can try to increase the excutor memory

Comment: spark-submit --files ./Conf/config.csv --py-files /home/sidd/abc.zip /home/Sidd/release/jobs/main.py --env dev --filename Transaction